# Silex + RememberMeServiceProvider - login from code

Tags: silex

I'm trying to make an ajax login form.
I've configured RememberMeServiceProvider according to http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/remember_me.html
It works great with default login form - the one that goes to 'login_path' and is managed by Silex.

I'm now trying to make custom login controller (AJAX only).
It looks like this:

```
public function ajaxLogin(Request $request, Application $app) {
    if (!AJAX)
        die;
    $email = $request->request->get('_username');
    $pass = $request->request->get('_password');
    if (!$email || !$pass)
        return 0;
    try {
        $user = APP::repo('users')->findOneByEmail($email);
        if (!$user)
            return 0;
        $encodedPass = $app['security.encoder_factory']->getEncoder($user)->encodePassword($pass, $user->getSalt());
        if ($encodedPass !== $user->getPassword())
            return 0;
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $pass, 'all', $user->getRoles());
        $app['security']->setToken($token);
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works great, but I have a problem with Remember Me option. How can I make it work with above custom login controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you bypass the security listerner to create the authentiated token by yourself.

To create the remember-me cookie, you must trigger the `loginSuccess` method of your [RememberMeServices](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.6.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.php).

```
$app['security.remember_me.service.my-firewall']->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);
```

Otherwise, you should implement your own PreAuthenticator :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html